# Share razor made variable with other web pages ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have variable defined in _layout.cshtml page like this:

```
@{
var username = "myusername";
var datetime = "mydatetime";
}
```

but these variables can be only used in _Layout page.

If I'm trying to use `@username` in Index.cshtml page, it returns "The name 'username' does not exist in the current context".

How can I make those variable global in order to use them in different pages?

Thanks.

Comment: in your *_Layout* change `var username = "myusername"` to `ViewBag.username = "myusername";` same with `datetime`.. then in your *Index.cshtml* all  you have to do is put `@ViewBag.username` wherever you want in

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/163532) to me. What is it that you're *actually* trying to achieve, because more likely than not, there's a far better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ViewBag for global variables.

```
@{
    ViewBag.username = "myusername";
    ViewBag.datetime = "mydatetime";
}
```

Render the values anywhere else using this syntax.

```
@ViewBag.username
@ViewBag.datetime
```

Comment: While this works, it's an extremely bad idea to have a view rely on some variable set in a layout. The whole point of layouts are that they should be interchangeable.

Comment: You are correct. He should really be using a ViewModel to set the values, but I was answering his immediate question.